Automatic Numbering and Cross-Referencing for Custom Elements (Research Questions, Objectives, Contributions)
I want to create a system for automatically numbering and cross-referencing custom elements (research questions, objectives, and contributions) in my LaTeX document. Specifically, I need:

Research questions numbered sequentially (1, 2, 3, ...)
Objectives numbered with their parent research question (1.1, 1.2, 2.1, ...)
Contributions numbered sequentially (1, 2, 3, ...)
The ability to cross-reference these elements using \cref{}, displaying their specific numbers rather than section numbers

Minimum Working Example (MWE):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\textbf{Research Question 1:} What is X? \label{rq:first}

\textbf{Objectives:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item To analyze A \label{obj:first}
    \item To investigate B \label{obj:second}
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Research Question 2:} What is Y? \label{rq:second}

\textbf{Objectives:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item To explore C \label{obj:third}
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Contribution 1:} This study provides Z \label{contrib:first}

\section{Main Content}

We address \cref{rq:first} through \cref{obj:first} and \cref{obj:second}.
\Cref{rq:second} is explored via \cref{obj:third}.
\Cref{contrib:first} summarizes our main contribution.

\end{document}

I would like the cross-references to display as:

Research question 1
Objective 1.1
Objective 1.2
Research question 2
Objective 2.1
Contribution 1

this is what I get now:

               

How can I achieve this automatic numbering and cross-referencing system?

If you don't want an enumerate, you could use something like \item \rq{rq:first} What is the first research question? where \rq{} produces Research question 1:  and generates a label you can refer to. you'd need a command for each type you wanted to refer to if you want separate numbering e.g \obj{} etc.

I am not sure if it is allowed, but I tried rewriting my question and updating the MWE from scratch for better clarity.

That‘s fine and wanted. It’s easier to read an updated well written question than trying to deduce it from a long row of clarifying comments.

The main aspects of the following solution are (a) the use of \StateRQ and \StateCont macros to state the research questions and contributions, respectively, and (b) the use of a bespoke enumerate-like list, called enumObj, to state objectives -- one objective per \item. Note that the numbers of the research questions, objectives, and contributions are generated automatically, i.e., by LaTeX.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for "\newlist" and "\setlist" macros
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

% define 2 counter variables
\newcounter{RQ}   % counter for "research question" items
\newcounter{Cont} % counter for "contribution" items

% define macros to state "research question" and "Contribution" items
\newcommand\StateRQ[1]{\refstepcounter{RQ}\label{#1}\textbf{Research question \theRQ}}
\newcommand\StateCont[1]{\refstepcounter{Cont}\label{#1}\textbf{Contribution \theCont}}

% define a bespoke enumerated list named "enumObj"
\newlist{enumObj}{enumerate}{1} % counter name: "enumObji"
\setlist[enumObj]{noitemsep,label=\theRQ.\arabic*}

% define the cleveref labels of the 3 new counters
\crefname{RQ}{research question}{research questions}
\crefname{Cont}{contribution}{contributions}
\crefname{enumObji}{objective}{objectives}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\StateRQ{rq:first}. What is X? 

\medskip\noindent
\textbf{Objectives:}
\begin{enumObj}
    \item To analyze \dots \label{obj:first}
    \item To investigate \dots \label{obj:second}
\end{enumObj}

\noindent
\StateRQ{rq:second}. What is Y?

\medskip\noindent
\textbf{Objective:}
\begin{enumObj}
    \item To explore \dots \label{obj:third}
\end{enumObj}

\noindent
\StateCont{contrib:first}. This study provides \dots 


\section{Main Content}

We address \cref{rq:first} by analyzing \cref{obj:first,obj:second}.
\Cref{rq:second} is explored via \cref{obj:third}.
\Cref{contrib:first} states the main result.

\end{document}

